# SpringMVC Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, java, rest

Начал изучать springMVC и пытаюсь сделать RESTful веб-приложение.

На страницу с БД выводится список книг, и по клику они должны удаляться. 
Пытаюсь сделать через `method = RequestMethod.DELETE` - получаю ошибку:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
> код контролера

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

private BookRepository bookRepository;

private BookValidator bookValidator;

@Autowired
public BookController(BookRepository bookRepository, BookValidator bookValidator) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    this.bookValidator = bookValidator;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBooks(Model model) {
    List<Book> books = this.bookRepository.ListAll();

    model.addAttribute("books", books);

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "deleteBook/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public  String deleteBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    this.bookRepository.removeBook(id);

    return "redirect:/";

}
```

index.jsp

```
<td>< a href="/deleteBook/${book.id}">delete</a></td>
```

В чем проблема, никак не могу понять, при том что если передавать 
`method = RequestMethod.GET`, а не `DELETE`, как я хочу, то все работает, а с `DELETE` нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, это не работает. Вам нужно использовать в форме метод `POST` и добавить еще один параметр `_method` со значением `DELETE`. А в `web.xml` добавить фильтр [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html), который бы ваш `POST` преобразовывал в `DELETE`.

См. также [вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629653/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-spring-mvc).

Comment: Правильно ли я делаю? Я добавил в web.xml

 <filter>
  <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: Нет, не правильно. Посмотрите пример на SO: `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>`

Comment:                     <form:form method="post"  action="" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="remove book">
                    </form:form>
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'DELETE' not supported
я не много не пойму что именно в моем случае должно быть в action. Контролер который удаляет книгу это BookController а именно метод deleteBook. Можно конкретно указать что там должно быть исходя из выше данного моего кода что бы я запомнил когда столкнусь с такими проблемами

Comment: У вас action="" пустой, а должен указывать на контроллер, который удаляет книгу.

Comment: Я не много не пойму, что именно в моем случае должно быть в action. Контроллер, который удаляет книгу, - это BookController, а именно метод deleteBook. Можно конкретно указать, что там должно быть, исходя из выше данного моего кода, чтобы я запомнил, когда столкнусь с такими проблемами?

Comment: Я передал deleteBook/10, и он удалил 1 книгу, но если я захочу удалить другую, то оно не выполнится, так как id другой книги уже будет не 10. Как можно передавать в action этот id, или в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

А по-твоему, каким методом ты отправляешь запрос здеся? Я вижу, что это отправляет GET:

```
<td>< a href="/deleteBook/${book.id}">delete</a></td>
```

Даже если бы ты пытался отправить PUT/DELETE из HTML формы, html не поддерживает PUT, DELETE их из формы.

[link1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms) [link2](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/method)

Comment: Как тогда правильно нужно отправлять?

Comment: я понимаю, что он передается как гет и то, что поддерживает html только get/post, но как тогда сделать с использованием DELETE?

Comment: всем спасибо, проблема решена